# Why does the OR operator behave like this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was always using the `||` as a nullish coalescing sort of operator. Either `A` or `B`.

But if I do something like,

```
1  const a = null
2  const b = '123'
3
4  console.log(a || b) // 123
5  console.log(a) || console.log(b) // null, 123
```

Why are BOTH console logs executed on line 5? Even if `a === null`, shouldn't it just execute the first console log, and not look at `console.log(b)`?

Comment: Why do you think the second `console.log` shouldn't be executed?!

Comment: Because it's either left side OR right side.. not both

Comment: @MikeK — The value the whole expression evaluates as is the LHS or the RHS. The code still has to be evaluated to find out which of those it should be.

Comment: It will have to *evaluate* both sides\* to be able to return a result… (\*if the LHS expression is falsey…)

Comment: The `A || B` operator always evaluates A first and only if A is falsy, then it evaluates B. `console.log()` always returns `undefined` which is a falsy value (just like `null`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) - regardless of the argument. That's why, after evaluating the first console log and receiving `undefined`, the second log always gets evaluated.

Comment: Are you alleging `console.log(null) === undefined`?

Comment: Yes. Try it. `console.log(console.log(a))` → `null` `undefined`

Comment: So the misconception on my part here is that even though `a` is null or not, `console.log` will print it, however return `undefined` regardless?

Comment: Yes. The function call evaluates to whatever value the function returns. `console.log` doesn't return anything, because, why would it, what's there to return for it?

Answer (score 4):

1. The left side is evaluated.
2. `console.log(a)` returns `undefined` (because that function *always* returns `undefined`)
3. Since the LHS evaluated as a falsy value: The right side is evaluated.

The value of `a` is irrelevant as that isn't what is on the LHS.